# Windows server 2008 r2: Backup notifications

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup

Is it possible to have Windows server 2008 r2 notify, preferably by e-mail, when a backup failed or had warnings?

We've had the issue of having backups that are incomplete (luckily detected before there was any need for the backups), but we don't want this to happen again. Knowing ourselves in that we probably will forget to log into the server every day to check this, I'd want a notification...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Task Scheduler to monitor events in Microsoft-Windows-Backup/Operational log, and email notification to you on errors and/or success.

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly correct.  However, I found a [great article](http://www.paulhite.com/2010/02/notification-wsb-can-do-notifications.html) describing in detail what and where are the setting to make-change-create. It includes a list of the error message that should be "flagged" and then the corresponding email would be sent. Note that you can setup one for failure and then another for successful backup.

Comment: We would prefer answers which contained details, rather than just links to other documents in case they get moved, deleted, modified, etc.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.